# Selecting specific printer by name VB

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, printing, servicecontroller

I've made a program that will run on startup asking the users to select their default printer. The code shows all installed printers in a ComboBox and the submit Button will set the Printer selected in the ComboBox as the default printer for that user.

Is there a way I can only show Printers names that contain specific text?
As e.g.:

```
ABC
printer1ABC
network1 abc
printer2 def
network2def
```

So it would only show `printer1ABC` and `network1 abc`?
Here's the code I have so far (one ComboBox and one Button)

```
Imports System.Drawing.Printing

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim strInstalledPrinters As String
        Dim prntDoc As New PrintDocument

        'check if there is installed printer
        If PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters.Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox("No printer installed")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'display installed printer into combobox list item
        For Each strInstalledPrinters In PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(strInstalledPrinters)
        Next strInstalledPrinters

        'Display current default printer on combobox texts
        ComboBox1.Text = prntDoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName

        Button1.Text = "Set Default Printer"
    End Sub
End Class
```

Function to set a printer as default:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Shell(String.Format("rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /y /n ""{0}""", ComboBox1.Text))

    MsgBox("You have changed your default printer")
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Sure can, just put your conditional criteria in the loop where your adding printers to the combo box items and only add them if it meets the criteria

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.installedprinters) is collection of string that enumerates the available Printer names. You can filter this collection in different ways to select only the Printers that you want to show.

Here, using LINQ's [Where()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where) method, the collection is filtered selectin strings that contain part of the name you're looking for:

```
dim myPrinters = PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters.OfType(Of String).
                 Where(Function(p) p.Contains("1ABC")).ToList()
```

You can add **`OrElse`** conditions to include other filters. E.g., :

```
.Where(Function(p) p.Contains("1ABC") OrElse p.StartsWith("Network1"))
```

Before enumerating the Printers, you should verify whether the Spooler Service is actually available. You can use the [ServiceController](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller) class to check the `Status` property of the **`spooler`** service, to see if it's [ServiceControllerStatus.Running](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontrollerstatus) and act on it. If the Spooler is not running, you get an exception if you try to enumerate the available printers in any way.
▶ Add a Project Reference to the `System.ServiceProcess` assembly.

You can also get other exceptions when you try to perform this enumeration, depending on different conditions, so better catch these exceptions and make different choices.

An example:
<sub>As a suggestion, give your Controls meaningful names, in case these are the actual names you're using</sub>

```
Imports System.Drawing.Printing
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.ServiceProcess

Private Const RPC_ERROR As Integer = 1722

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Button1.Text = "Set Default Printer"
    Button1.Enabled = False

    Dim spoolerStatus = New ServiceController("spooler").Status

    If spoolerStatus = ServiceControllerStatus.Running Then
        Try
            Dim myPrinters = PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters.OfType(Of String).
                Where(Function(p) p.Contains("1ABC")).ToList()
            If myPrinters.Count > 0 Then
                ComboBox1.DataSource = myPrinters
                Button1.Enabled = True
            Else
                ComboBox1.Items.Add("<Printer not installed>")
            End If
        Catch wEx As Win32Exception
            If wEx.NativeErrorCode = RPC_ERROR Then
                ' RPC Server unavailable
                ComboBox1.Items.Add($"<{wEx.Message}>")
            Else
                ' Log Message
                MessageBox.Show(wEx.Message)
                ComboBox1.Items.Add("<Error>")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            ' Log Message
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            ComboBox1.Items.Add("<Error>")
        End Try
    Else
        ComboBox1.Items.Add("<Spooler Service not available>")
    End If
    ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
End Sub
```

---

To change the default printer, I suggest to use the [SetdefaultPrinter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/setdefaultprinter) Win32 function or the corresponding WMI's [Win32_Printer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-printer) class [SetDefaultPrinter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/setdefaultprinter-method-in-class-win32-printer) method.

▶ When you click your Button to set the new default Printer, use the [GetItemText()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.getitemtext) method to get the `ComboBox1.SelectedItem` content, don't rely on the Text property of that Control.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

<DllImport("winspool.drv", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True)>
Friend Shared Function SetDefaultPrinter(printerName As String) As Boolean
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim printeNname = ComboBox1.GetItemText(ComboBox1.SelectedItem)
    If SetDefaultPrinter(printeNname) Then
         MessageBox.Show($"Your default printer is now {printeNname}")
    Else
         MessageBox.Show("Couldn't change the default printer")
    End If
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect! this has made my script function as i wanted it to! much appreciated!