# How to set Paper Size A5,PageOrientation,Set name Printer in a web browser control with code in VB.NET

Tags: windows, vb.net, winforms, printing, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to set Paper Size A5,PageOrientation,Set name Printer in a web browser control with code in VB.NET

I tried no webbrowser effect, is there anything I am wrong with the code I please guide me.

I tried according to this link : [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46836345/how-to-set-paper-size-and-margins-printing-from-a-web-browser-control)

Thanks

```
 Private Sub pagesetupkey()
        Dim pageSetupKey As String = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"
        Dim isWritable As Boolean = True
        Dim rKey As RegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(pageSetupKey, isWritable)
        ' Use 1 for Portrait and 2 for Landccape 
        rKey.SetValue("PageOrientation", 2, RegistryValueKind.DWord)
        ' Specifies paper size. Valid settings are 1=letter, 5=Legal, 9=A4, 13=B5.Default setting is 1.
        rKey.SetValue("PaperSize", 9, RegistryValueKind.DWord)
        ' Specifies print quality
        rKey.SetValue("PrintQuality ", 1, RegistryValueKind.DWord)
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Using dt = LoadData("A")
            Call pagesetupkey()
            myWebBrowser.DocumentText = DataTableToHtml(dt)
        End Using
    End Sub
    Private Sub myWebBrowser_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles myWebBrowser.DocumentCompleted
        Call pagesetupkey()
        myWebBrowser.ShowPrintPreviewDialog()
        'myWebBrowser.Print()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        myWebBrowser.Parent = Me
    End Sub
```

[image: result in print pagesetup webbrowser controll]

Comment: Do any of the answers to [CSS to set A4 paper size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649943/css-to-set-a4-paper-size) help?

Comment: Set the default printer to apply the settings. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65946161/14171304

Comment: @AndrewMorton , 
there is no answer with the problem I posted

Comment: @dr.null , `Set the default printer to apply the settings. See` Thank you for your response I will try